# Transfer Session data from one form to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I am working on a project for school in Visual Studio 2015.  I have two pages, both have a last name text box.  I need to transfer the lastname on form 1 to the last name textbox on form 2.

Here is what i have:

**FORM 1**: Under the button on click event:

```
Session["Lname"] = TextBox2.Text;
```

**FORM 2**: Page Load

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    lastName.Text = (string)Session["Lname"];
}
```

It's probably a simple fix that I just can't see and might need a second set of eyes on.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is what you need to do. Next time you are in class, go slap your teacher in the face for teaching you to code this way. Seriously. I would be more than happy to debate what he is trying to do.

There are a couple of ways to solve this:

1. Put the information in session on page 1 and then redirect. This is basically what you are trying. The problem with this methodology is it makes the application stateful, which can be problematic in some scaling situations. It is hard to find anyone suggesting using state in this manner, especially since ASP.NET MVC, which is stateless, is used.
2. You can change the target of the form so it submits to form 2 instead of form 1. This is done by changing the PostBackUrl property of the page. The problem with this method is you can just as easily do it with one page. Except in a few instances, I see no reason to do this. If you want to go this route, check [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178140.aspx) out.

There are other variations. You might even write both of these methods and impress the shit out of your prof, and then slap him in the face and show him how this is done in a single page. Or, better yet, show him an ASP.NET MVC version on top of everything you have done thus far and show him you have entered the modern age. ;-)

Comment: Thank you, he has us using the web forms and the second half of the project is similar to the first using MVC.  He has said that MVC is the better way to go but we are learning how to use forms too.  But he has gone more indepth on the MVC.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load the second form on post back, try to change it to:

```
if (!IsPostBack) { lastName.Text = (string)Session["Lname"]; }
```

Good luck with school!

Comment: This is part of the solution. Still need to use PostBackUrl property of form 1 to form 2.

Comment: It is hard to tell what he is trying to do, if you are using the good old sessions you don't really need postback url... though not sure in this day and age why would one use sessions for simple tasks.

Comment: Very true @albattran. That is why I suggested he slap his teacher. ;-)

Comment: Thanks everyone, yeah I am getting pretty PO'd at this assignment.  I have two things that just won't work no matter what I try.  I have more complicated things that work and the most simple things that don't.  Grrr.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, in page 1 you need to make sure that `TextBox2.Text` is not null or empty

```
if(TextBox2.Text != "" && TextBox2.Text != null)
{
  Session["Lname"] = TextBox2.Text;
}
else
{
 // just for test in case TextBox2.Text is null,
  Session["Lname"] = "it is null..";
}
```

and then you can read session in page 2 like

```
lastName.Text = Session["Lname"].ToString();
```